# Setting of BaseIntermediateOutputPath prevents running .targets from Nuget

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have MSVS 2017 (15.3) and the following problem. My project references *System.Data.SQLite* which contains *targets* file that copies some native dlls to output folder. All works correctly (dlls appear in correct place) until I specify value for *BaseIntermediateOutputPath* parameter in props file. After setting parameter build is successful but dlls are missing.

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="common.net.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.105.2" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Imported props has the following content

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SolutionDir>
    <Configuration Condition="$(Configuration) == ''">Debug</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SynOutDir>$(TargetFramework)_$(Platform)_$(Configuration)</SynOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseOutputPath>../bin/</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>../tmp/$(MSBuildProjectName)/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)$(SynOutDir)</OutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
    <LangVersion>7</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit a known issue in MSBuild caused by import order. In MSBuild 15, the "SDK" attribute on <Project> is an implicit top/bottom import. Your import happens too late.

Changing the order should solve the issue. You could do it like this:

```
<Project>
   <Import Project="common.net.props" />
   <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

   <!-- the rest of your project -->
   <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
</Project>
```

You can also name your file "Directory.Build.props" and it will magically be imported for you. 
See https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1603

Comment: Note that a `Directory.Build.props` file would be imported early enough in the common props to correctly set `BaseIntermediateOutputPath`.

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer to include that tip. We started used Directory.Build.props in most of our projects recently. It's may be a little too "magic" for some, but it lets you keep `<Project Sdk="..." />`